# Pandas remove rows based on timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thanks in advance for checking out my question and help me out!

Basically what I am trying to do is removing MAC addresses which haven't been detected in the past hour or even longer than that.

I collect probe requests from my wifi network with timestamps for each MAC captured. The data is processed using Pandas. The dataframe has only 2 columns: 'MAC' and 'TIME' (in strftime format). Below is a screenshot of my dataframe.

As you can see I will only consider rows which have same MAC address are 'duplicates'. My problem is I can't find out each duplicated MAC addresses' time gap between the last one and the one before last.
[MAC csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtI4.png)
[MAC csv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dzjq.png)
What I have tried so far:
I tried to use groupby and tail(2) to group data by MAC and take the last 2 entries however when there are several duplicated MACs in the dataframe this won't work because this method seems to only work for the last two entries.
Here is the code I tried:

```
def CheckListCleaner(inputDF) -> pd.DataFrame:
         sleep(60 - time() % 60)
         cond1 = inputDF.groupby("MAC").count() > 1
         cond2 = inputDF.groupby("MAC").tail(2).diff() > 3600
         combined_cond = cond1.mul(cond2)
         combined_cond["M1"] = combined_cond.index
         combined_cond.rename({"T": "val"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
         out = inputDF.merge(combined_cond, left_on="MAC", right_on="M1")
         listToDel = out[~out["val"]]
         return listToDel
```

I am open to any new ideas. I am also wondering whether there are some easier ways or libs I can use to make this work without using a lot groupby and conditions.

P.S. In case you wonder how did I captured these MAC addresses. I am only interested in type 2 transmitter MACs. Below is the code I used to collect MACS.

```
def PacketHandler(pkt):
if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.type == 0:
            allType2List.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 1 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            allType2List.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 2 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            allType2List.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
        if pkt.type == 3 and pkt.addr2 != None:
            allType2List.append((pkt.addr2, datetime.fromtimestamp(pkt.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
```

Comment: Just to understand more about your question, do you want to first remove the duplicated MAC addresses with the same timestamp?

Comment: Hi Ali, it is actually not necessary because what really matters is the last one (meaning the latest captured) of each duplicated MAC and the one before last but i guess it will make the dataframe look cleaner